# How to handle sub-domain and custom domain request with ssl (ELB & Nginx)

Tags: nginx, ssl, next.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a ec2 instance where an nextjs app I'm having. basically my app does one thing, it extracts host header (website url) and does an api call to backend and backend sends appropriate data to that website url( it's kinda sub-domain and custom domain game like shopify)

test case one:-
visitor enter's store1.salesklik.com.
my AWS route 53 has one record that says any subdomain request to salesklik.com (e.g.- *.salesklik.com) will be routed to an elastic load balancer which then sends it to my EC2.
and once the nextjs app gets the website url, app will call the backend and paint the data appropriately. and all my *.salesklik.com domains are secured by AWS ACM ssl.

Test case two:-
Some business added custom domain in their business. now it's not just accessible at store1.salesklik.com, but store1.com also.
and they have their own domain purchasing dns provider like godaddy.
what I can provide to them is my IP and they will add it to their dns configuration (A record, as same as shopify does).  but how to grab the request and send it to nextjs app ? cause even If I grab that request, it won't be SSL secured as custom domain are not registered in my EC2 nginx ssl conf.

what is the workaround ?
If you want more brief about our platform and have some suggestion, please let me know

Comment: you can attach 1 ACM certificate to an ALB. That certificate will have to have a SAN for each additional DNS name for which the cert must be valid, and each of those DNS names must be validated before the cert is activated.  For something like this, it might make more sense to use an NLB and terminate the SSL on the instance rather than the load balancer.  You can then use ACME certs with the HTTP challenge (https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/) .  You'll still have to configure nginx to answer with the appropriate cert.

Comment: SSL will be handled by nginx with each customdomain.conf and its relevant certbot SSL keys. is that what you are trying to say ? 

so should I stop using the AWS ACM for *.salesklik.com and move it to nginx & certbot HTTPS validation ?

and I didn't get the first method fully, but what I've extracted is that I have to manually (or automatically, if possibly) need to verify or add each custom domain to one ACM record.


Thanks for the solution btw.

Comment: "should I stop using the AWS ACM"  Yes, I suggest you consider it, because "I have to manually (or automatically, if possibly) need to verify or add each custom domain to one ACM record" this would require further coordination with the administrator of eg `store1.com` while the HTTP challenge type will work with just an A record to your NLB.

Comment: Clearly understood...